# Unity Disorted Audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

I'm having issues playing Audio Clips in Unity.

I want my Shark to produce a "bite" sound when the player is detected but the sound is distorted.

The rest of the code is running as intended.

Can I have a code review and suggestion please?

What am I possibly doing wrong (when calling the Audio Source to Play)?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shark2Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform leftPoint;
    public Transform rightPoint;

    public float startSpeed;
    public float swimSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
    public bool swimmingRight;


    public float superSpeed;
    public Transform puntoA;
    public Transform puntoB;
    public LayerMask whatIsPlayer;
    public bool playerDetected;

    private Animator myAnim;

    public AudioSource bite;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        swimSpeed = startSpeed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        playerDetected = Physics2D.OverlapArea (puntoA.position, puntoB.position, whatIsPlayer);
        myAnim.SetBool ("Player Detected", playerDetected);

        if (playerDetected) 
        {
            swimSpeed = superSpeed;
            bite.Play ();
        } 


        if (swimmingRight && transform.position.x > rightPoint.position.x) 
        {
            swimmingRight = false;
        }

        if (!swimmingRight && transform.position.x < leftPoint.position.x) 
        {
            swimmingRight = true;
        }



        if (swimmingRight) 
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector3 (swimSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y, 0f);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
        else 
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector3 (-swimSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y, 0f);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    }

    public void ResetShark2Speed()
    {
        swimSpeed = startSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but the sound is distorted"_ How? Is it a volume-level distortion? Also should `bite.Play();` be triggered every frame update? What if your FPS is 60, do you really want `bite` to start playing 60 times for each 1 seconds? It won't sound good, I expect a (possible) buzzing/stuttering noise... maybe that's what you call distortion?

Comment: That´s correct, It was a buzzing noise. Thank you very much for your explanation, I was not clear about using Audio Source during the Update ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is that you're **re-playing the sound at every screen update** (based on your app's framerate). It's not clear if you want it to loop (since is placed inside a `void Update` function for repeated instructions) or you simply want it to play once per detection.

If Unity can detect when a sound is playing or has finished then use that to help fix this.

The looping logic is:

- On each frame update, check if sound is already in "playing" mode.
- If No... assume sound "ended" and you can now do `bite.Play();`.
- Else-If Yes... let sound continue (maybe it'll be "ended" in a future frame check).

A pseudo-code example:

```
if (playerDetected == true) 
{
    swimSpeed = superSpeed;

    if( bite.isPlaying == true)
    {
        //# Do nothing or whatever you need
    }
    else 
    {
        //# Asssume it's not playing (eg: stopped, ended, not started, etc)
        bite.Play (); 
    }
}
```

For once-per-detection:

```
public bool detect_snd_Played;

detect_Snd_Played = false;  //# Not yet played since no "detect"

//# Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (playerDetected == true) { swimSpeed = superSpeed; }

    if (detect_Snd_Played == false) 
    {
        bite.Play ();
        detect_Snd_Played = true; //# Stops future playback until you reset to false
    }
}
```

This line `detect_Snd_Played = true;` should stop multiple playbacks until you reset. This could be if your player becomes "un-detected" by shark, and you can now reset for next time's new "detection" process...

Comment: Wao, thank you VERY MUCH for such a quick response and the incredible explanation. I want the sound effect to play just when the player is detected, so I will use the second piece of code. I´m new to Unity , and I this issue with audio clips was breaking my head, this will be so useful for me :) Gracias amigo!

Comment: Because I wanted the Sound to loop while the player was detected, I use the first piece of code and works perfectly fine, THANK YOU ONCE AGAIN!